# Looking for a simple way to pass a react component, and get it's output html

Tags: command-line-interface, react-rendering

As part of my job, I need a command line script that I can pass a react component to, and get the parsed html. As much as possible, I would like it to happen, without any background servers - just something like this

`render.js /path/to/component.js '{"param1" : 11}'`

I tried react-render-cli, but it keeps saying:
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Using "react": "17.0.2", "react-render-cli": "0.14.1"

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString

Comment: This is not a command line interface. How can I make it into one?

Comment: Just create a cli program with the help of that

Comment: Sure, but than I'll get issues with SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when I try to import the react component

Comment: You have to use a preprocessor. I would recommend you to check on how JSX compiled with [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-preset-react)

Comment: While it's definatly not a simple way, it mostly works. Now here's the mostly part, and if you'll help with this, I'll be super grateful:
I managed to get the html, but now I'm trying to pull the sass into a single CSS file. Any chance you have an idea how I can do that?

Comment: You can build your react project and grab the css file from the build result or if it is not what you want maybe you'll have to write a build script. Maybe with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#getting-started)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I found some other way, as this became one hellish solution.